# How to set a default value for a float field using django models?

Tags: python, django, django-models

```
from django.db import models
class doctors(models.Model):
    docid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True) # Need autoincrement, unique and primary
    name = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    regid = models.CharField(max_length=15, default="")
    photo = models.CharField(max_length=35, default="")
    email = models.EmailField(default="")
    phone = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True)
    qualifications = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
    about = models.CharField(max_length=35, default="")
    specialities = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
    department = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="ENT")
    fees = models.FloatField(default=300.0, null=True)
    displayfee = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True)
    slotrange = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slotdurn = models.IntegerField(default=10, null=True)
    breakrange = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
    slotsleft = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
```

**What I intended:** If one of the fields like phone, fees, displayfee, or slotdurn is not specified, they should be filled in a default value. Unfortunately these are filled with an automatic value of NULL when I do the following:

```
from appointments.models import doctors
doc=doctors(name="Dr Joel", regid="12524", email="joel@mydomain.com")
doc.save()
```

I checked the sql created, and it is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `appointments_doctors` (
`docid` int(11) NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(35) NOT NULL,
`regid` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
`photo` varchar(35) NOT NULL,
`email` varchar(254) NOT NULL,
`phone` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`qualifications` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`about` varchar(35) NOT NULL,
`specialities` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`department` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`fees` double DEFAULT NULL,
`displayfee` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`slotrange` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`slotdurn` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`breakrange` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`slotsleft` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

It seems the default value I specified is being overridden by the Null value. I added the null because previously I was being prompted that these fields cannot be null, even when I had specified the default value.

Edit: After removing the float, my class looks like this:

```
class doctors(models.Model):
    docid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True) # Need autoincrement, unique and primary
    name = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    regid = models.CharField(max_length=15, default="")
    photo = models.CharField(max_length=35, default="")
    email = models.EmailField(default="")
    phone = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    qualifications = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
    about = models.CharField(max_length=35, default="")
    specialities = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
    department = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="ENT")
    fees = models.FloatField(default=300.0)
    displayfee = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    slotrange = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slotdurn = models.IntegerField(default=10)
    breakrange = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
    slotsleft = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
```

Migration script looks like this:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('appointments', '0006_auto_20180726_0502'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='doctors',
            name='displayfee',
            field=models.IntegerField(default=0),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='doctors',
            name='fees',
            field=models.FloatField(default=300.0),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='doctors',
            name='phone',
            field=models.IntegerField(default=0),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='doctors',
            name='slotdurn',
            field=models.IntegerField(default=10),
        ),
    ]
```

But the generated sql still does not have the default values. How can I specify these in the model and have it migrated to sql? I'm using django 2.0.7 on python 3.6.5.

What is the correct way to create the model?

Comment: Why do you have both `default` and `null` keyword arguments?

Comment: When default alone was specified, I couldnt add an entry without giving the value. I got the error that these couldnt be null.

Comment: Did you check the migration script when you removed `null`? Is it same as one posted above?

Comment: @bro-grammer After removing null, and specifying default like above, This is the migration script https://pastebin.com/E8F2jkuz And this is the sql created: https://pastebin.com/Lredj1ve. The default values I specified arent being added.

Comment: @Droidzone use blank=True to allow null values in the form. Don't use both null and default at the same time. Also you I think default values are handled by Django and not postgres. while you save the model instance default should work.

Comment: @KireetiK The defaults I specified are not being saved to the sql schema. This is the generated migrations: https://pastebin.com/C0Jn1Txu And this is the generated sql: https://pastebin.com/a011xjKe

Comment: I'm not sure if Django sets default in the DB. Try saving the form and see if the default works.

Comment: I tried saving. I found that django doesnt set default in database schema. What would be a pythonic solution for this?

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't reproduce the behavior. Anyway try to remove `null` parameter from the fields that have `default` parameter.